# A question related to convergence of a sequence of functions and their derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f$ defined as $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$ and $0$ elsewhere. There is a sequence of **smooth** functions $\{f_n\}$, such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Also $V(f_n)\to V(f) = 2$ where $V(f)$ is the [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) of function $f$ in the inetrval $(-1,1)$. Does the sequence of functions $\{f_n'\}$ converge? How do $f_n'$ look like when $n$ is large? Here $f_n'$ is the derivative of $f_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical example you might construct, both $f_n$ and $f'_n$ will be near $0$ when $x$ is not near $0$, with $f$ having a large positive "spike" near $x=0$, and $f'$ correspondingly being large and positive in some interval slightly to the left of $0$, large and negative in some interval slightly to the right of $0$.

However, things can be 
somewhat more complicated, e.g. it's also not hard to find examples
where $f'_n(x) \to \pm\infty$ as $n \to \infty$ for some infinite set of values of $x$.

Comment: Can we say $||f_n||_{L^{\infty}} \to 1$?

Comment: Yes we can.  It's at least $1$ because $f_n(0) \to 1$.  It's at most $1$ because otherwise $\limsup_n V(f_n) > 1$.

Comment: Let $S(f_n)$ = sum of absolute values of $f_n$ at its maxima and minima, can we say $S(f_n) \to 1$

Comment: @ RobertIsrael : Related new question of mine http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2132785/2987