# A question on bounded variation and sum of absolute values at points of extrema.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a function $f$ defined on $(-a,a)$ as $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0$ and $0$ elsewhere. There is a sequence of **smooth** functions $\{f_n\}$ defined on $(-a,a)$, such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Also $V(f_n)\to V(f) = 2$ where $V(f)$ is the [variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation) of function $f$ in the inetrval $(-a,a)$.

Lets define the set of points of extrema of function $f_n$ as $E_n = \left\{x/x \in (-a,a)\wedge f_n'(x) = 0\right\}$. and $$\beta_n = \sum\limits_{x\in E_n}\left|f_n(x)\right|$$

I am tempted to say that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\beta_n = 1$$

Is this  justified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  For example, $f_n$ could have two maxima near $x=0$ with a local minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: Ah! This sounds like a death knell! Thanks for  the answer Prof Robert.